# Modificar macro para que no muestre el mensaje de datos copiados

Tags: excel

Buen tarde comunidad,

Tengo el siguiente macro lo que hace es copiar todos los archivos .txt que se encuentren dentro de su misma carpeta, toma la segunda columna de cada archivo y la copia a una hoja de excel  columna por columna de forma consecutiva al momento de copiar me muestra una ventana que me dice que hay demasiados datos y me pregunta si los quiero almacenar dándome 3 opciones, lo que quiero saber es como puedo quitar esa ventana y lo haga de modo automático.

Adjunto el macro:

```html
Sub Macro_lectura()
mio = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ruta = ActiveWorkbook.Path
ChDir ruta & "\"
archi = Dir("*.txt")
Do While archi <> ""
Workbooks.OpenText archi, origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited
otro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Range("b1:b" & Range("b65000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Workbooks(mio).Activate
Range("av2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Workbooks(otro).Close False
archi = Dir()
Loop
ActiveSheet.Columns("a:a").EntireColumn.Delete
MsgBox "proceso terminado"
End Sub
```

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: No creo que funcione, pero prueba con `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.y luego cuando ya termine todo el código vuelve a activarlas con `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: Hola Elier , pues efectivamente funciono te agradesco la atencion Suldos.

Comment: Estupendo, lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

prueba con `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.y luego cuando ya termine todo el código vuelve a activarlas con `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`